# Solving non concave quadratic function in matlab with constraints

Tags: matlab, optimization, quadratic

How can I solve non concave quadratic function in matlab with constraints. I tried using quadprog but it doesn't work

I have to optimize a function f=x'Ax with constraints that sum of xs is equal to 1 and 0<=x<=1. My function is not concave. So I just need to maximize. It's ok if I find a local maxima even though global would be better.

I tried using matlab's quadprog function. However, it's results are not that good. I don't know it terminates but the results are not that go. I want something that will just iterate the number of times, I tell it to and gives me the results

I am trying to implement something like this

http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=68DD5FE71FCEB5629F1FA0F1E02CCFE8?doi=10.1.1.157.6789&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Well, my problem scenario is I have a set of points and labels. So the job is to match the points with labels. I define a graph with all the possible (node,label) pairs. And define a affinity matrix of size (number_node_label pairs, number_node_label pairs)

And I want to maximize the function x'Ax with the constraints that sum of xs = 1. all xs >=0 i.e the point lies in a simplex.

For my affinity matrix

A(u,v) where u and v are one of the point,label pairs i.e, u=point1,label1 v=point2, label2 suppose

A(u,v) = exp(-abs(||point1-point2||-||label1-label2||)) / sigma
A(u,v) = 0 if u==v

I want something like replicator equation

Comment: It would also be more helpful if you _show_ what you have tried, and possibly include a sample input with desired results. **EDIT** I've also found [this article](http://download.springer.com/static/pdf/281/art%253A10.1007%252FBF00539118.pdf?auth66=1355092590_9602a40ab218b82ad6ce19e7f35d475a&ext=.pdf). Maybe it can help...

Comment: Well I need something similar to replicator equation. But not exactly replicator equation

Comment: @Plus I want to know how it is different whether I use replicator equation or use quadprog

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more. I didn't get it

Comment: @DanielFischer Can you explain more. I didn't get it actually. How come I can directly get it?

Comment: @DanielFischer, but the diagonal elements are 0. So will it be possible?

Comment: Ah, sorry, I was wrong. It's not so simple.

Comment: Are you sure the results found are not so good? Perhaps you could try brute forcing a bit and either find solutions or at least confirm that quadprog really underperforms.